# return message in linq

Tags: mysql, linq, list, wcf

how to return a message in linq? please see my code below. my return type is list. please help me.

```
public List<Product> GetProductsByProductName(string storeId, string productName)
{
    Authenticate();
    int _storeId = Convert.ToInt32(storeId);
    string message = "Item is not added to cart";
    var _products = (from p in context.products.AsEnumerable()
                     where p.StoreId == _storeId && p.ProductName.Contains(productName) && p.ProductIsAvailable.Equals(true)
                     orderby p.ProductName
                     select
                         new Product()
                         {
                             ProductName = p.ProductName,
                             CategoryID = p.CategoryId,
                             QuantityPerUnit = p.ProductUnit,
                             UnitPrice = p.ProductPrice,
                             DiscountValue = p.DiscountValue,
                             DiscountType = p.DiscountType
                         }).ToList();

    if (_products.Count > 0)
    {
        return _products;
    }
    else
    {
        return message.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should consider throwing an exception.
instead of return meassage.toList try :

throw new Exception("Item is not added to cart");

```
public List<Product> GetProductsByProductName(string storeId, string productName)
{
    ...

    if (_products.Count > 0)
    {
        return _products;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception( "Item is not added to cart");

    }
}
```

you can handle it outside where you call the GetProductsByProductName method

you can even define your own exception like ItemAddException : Exception ....

or you add a new out bool parameter that tells you if it worked, or an out string parameter for messages :)

```
public List<Product> GetProductsByProductName(string storeId, string productName, out string message)
    {
        ...

        if (_products.Count > 0)
        {
            return _products;
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Item is not added to cart";
            return null; //check if caller can handle nulls ;)
        }
    }
```

so if the method was called

```
var l = GetProductsByProductName(storeId, productName);
```

you will now have to do

```
string message="";
var l = GetProductsByProductName(string storeId, string productName, out message);
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(message)==false) 
{
   .... do stuff
}
```

or if you use the exception mehtod :

```
try 
{ 
  var l = GetProductsByProductName(storeId, productName); 
}
catch(Excepion ex)
{ 
   ... do stuff 
}
```

Comment: That's a ref not an out.

Comment: sorry, it is not working. actually i want return a message to  mobile. this is using for mobile application.

Comment: maybe you should post the calling method too :) means : the caller must handle the out string, or the exception